# Should I run the all unicorn processes as www-data (non-root)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicorn

I'm running a a Rails 3 application with Unicorn and Nginx. Currently, Unicorns runs as root and due to this line in unicorn.rb:

```
user "www-data"
```

but I'm wondering whether I should just run all Unicorn process as www-data. Would there be any problem doing that? I'm using a file socket, so opening a port (<1024) is not an issue I'll have. Anything else I should be aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be running your application as root.  This gives the application root permissions which in turn means that if you make a mistake and expose the file system, an attacker can have root permissions without much effort.

I avoid running as www-data or other shared users.  Instead I create a user for the specific app and give them their own unique permissions.  In my case, I am running multiple applications on one server and this allows for an added layer of protection in case one app is compromised.

Here is a good read on some of the things that can go wrong: https://jhalderm.com/pub/papers/dcvoting-fc12.pdf

Comment: So, do you think the user switching feature of unicorn (and some other web servers) shouldn't exist?

Comment: I prefer not to use it.  When it comes to system administration I am overly cautious.  Who would have expected something like Paperclip to have exposed such vulnerabilities? It is not that they shouldn't exist, it shouldn't be necessary if the systems are setup correctly.

Comment: Note: the issue with paperclip was addressed, i just am using that as an example of how assuming that third party software is secure can be a mistake.